# Can a memory pool allocate things with a `'static` lifetime?

Tags: rust

I was looking at https://rphmeier.github.io/allocators/allocators/freelist/struct.FreeList.html:

```
impl FreeList<'static, HeapAllocator> {
    //fn new(...)
}

impl<'a, A: 'a + Allocator> Allocator for FreeList<'a, A> {
    fn allocate<T>(&self, val: T) -> Result<AllocBox<T, Self>, (Error, T)> where Self: Sized
}
```

for the `'static` case, `AllocBox<T, Self>` is also `'static` (because `Self` is `'static`), which means that the allocated memory and the allocator are independent (one does not contain a reference to the other). Which means that if the allocator is dropped, the memory can still live. How is it possible? **Shouldn't the allocated memory keep a reference to the memory pool so it knows where to go back once it's dropped?**

Can someone give me an example of a memory pool in Rust that allocates with `'static` lifetime? I think this is one example, but it's not maintained since 2017.

Comment: My guess is that that allocator just delegates to the OS (basically, to `malloc`) to get its memory. Since this is Rust, we still know when we need to `drop` (i.e. `free`), and since Rust is not managing the memory pool anymore (your OS is), we don't need to keep an explicit Rust-side reference to anything.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo this is not my main concern. How does the memory go back to the allocator when it drops?

Answer (score 2):

> for the `'static` case, `AllocBox<T, Self>` is also `'static` (because `Self` is `'static`), which means that the allocated memory and the allocator are independent

Your interpretation is incorrect, you've misapplied how elided lifetimes are determined. With explicit lifetimes, the code should be read like this (roughly):

```
impl<'a, A: 'a + Allocator> Allocator for FreeList<'a, A> {
    fn allocate<'b, T>(&'b self, val: T) -> Result<AllocBox<'b, T, Self>, (Error, T)> where Self: Sized
}
```

The returned `AllocBox` is bound to the lifetime of `self` (the instance), not `'a` of `Self`. So if the free list were to be dropped, it would yield a compiler error if any allocations lingered.

> Shouldn't the allocated memory keep a reference to the memory pool so it knows where to go back once it's dropped?

It does. From the [source](https://rphmeier.github.io/allocators/src/allocators/boxed.rs.html#11-16), an `AllocBox` does keep a reference to the original allocator which is used in the `Drop` implementation.

---

> Can someone give me an example of a memory pool in Rust that allocates with `'static` lifetime?

You can create an allocator that yields allocations with a `'static` lifetime if the allocator itself were `'static`. This can be demonstrated in this crate by allocating via the [`HEAP`](https://rphmeier.github.io/allocators/allocators/constant.HEAP.html) constant.

Or as @SilvioMayolo suggests in the comments, a different allocator interface could yield `'static` references if it simply deferred to the standard [`Global`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Global.html) allocator.

Comment: Ok, but in the case of a static allocator like HEAP, how does the allocated memory keep a reference to the memory allocator, if AllocBox is supposed to be static?

Comment: @Rafaelo I'm not sure what you mean. If you use `HEAP`, then `self` is `'static`, then `AllocBox<'static, ...>` is returned.

Comment: How can AllocBox<'static> keep a reference to its allocator if there's no lifetime in its parameters? All references require a lifetime that is not static

Comment: @Rafaelo There is nothing wrong with `&'static HeapAllocator`. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: So the HeapAllocator does not recycle memory, it always allocate a new one?

Comment: @Rafaelo No, a `AllocBox<'static, ...>` can be dropped and have its allocation freed. I'm not sure where your confusion stems from, but maybe give [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) a read?

Comment: I know `AllocBox` can have its allocation freed, but how does it know where to return for being reused, if any reference to the memory pool object would have to be non static?

Comment: @Rafaelo It knows where to return it since `AllocBox` *does* keep a reference to the memory pool object (as linked in my answer). Why do you think that would have to be non-static?

Comment: @Rafaelo I'll try to put it another way. `AllocBox` *does* have a generic lifetime parameter (`'a`) which is used to reference the memory pool object (`allocator: &'a A`). As shown above, the parameter used for that generic lifetime is dependent on the lifetime of the allocator (`&'b self` -> `AllocBox<'b, ...>`). In the specific case where the allocator object has a static lifetime (`&'static self`), the `AllocBox` is thus given `'static` as that lifetime parameter (`AllocBox<'static, ...>`) and therefore the reference to the memory object is as well (`allocator: &'static A`).

Comment: @Rafaelo And references *can* be static (`&'static _`) if what it references is static.